# $T$ is compact iff every closed subspace in $Ran(T)$ is finite dimensional.

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $T$ be a continuous linear operator on Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Prove that $T$ is compact **if** and only if every closed subspace contained in the range of $T$ is finite dimensional.

---

For the left side implies the right side, it is a consequence of open-mapping theorem. But on the other hand I don’t know how to deal with. I tried to use finite rank operator to approach $T$, but field.
Any hint or references? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the polar decomposition one may assume that $T\geq0$.

In this case, for every $n$, let $f_n$ be the characteristic function of $[1/n,\infty)$.
The function
$$
  g_n(t) = f_n(t)/t,
  $$
is then  bounded and $f_n(t)=tg_n(t)$.  Therefore $f_n(T)=Tg_n(T)$,  so we see that the range of $f_n(T)$ is contained
in the range of $T$.  Since $f_n(T)$ is a projection, its range is closed, so by hypothesis we deduce that $f_n(T)$ has
finite rank.

Observing that  $Tf_n(T)$ converges  to $T$, we conclude that  $T$ is compact.

Comment: The claim is that the range of $f_n(T)$ (not $Tf_n(T)$) is closed, and contained in the range of $T$.

Comment: @Landau $f_n(T)$ has finite-rank so $T f_n(T)$ has finite-dimensional range and thus closed range. That the range of $T f_n(T)$ is contained in the range of $T$ is trivial.

Comment: Oh, spectra decomposition is so powerful! Thank you, Ruy.

Comment: You are welcome! Indeed spectral theory (and functional calculus in particular) is a fantastic tool!